# Process files as soon as they are downloaded

Tags: python, json, concurrency, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

I have a script which downloads a lot of JSONs. I am processing the JSONs after they are downloaded and I am sending them to some other functions. Presently, I am just waiting till all the JSONs are downloaded and then processing each of them. Is there any way to do this parallelly? Like, as soon as each JSON is downloaded, move it to perform some tasks on it.

I am thinking to use RabbitMQ which sends the consumer the path of the JSON after it has been fully downloaded. I have no clue how to determine whether a JSON has been downloaded and is ready to use it.

I have looked at other answers, but I couldn't find anything clear. I just want an idea on how to continue with the concurrency part or how to take the just downloaded JSON to next process.

Comment: You can try the mix of `threading` and `Queue` modules. Make the request, queue and download as soon as available.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But there could be a JSON which is in the downloading process right? How would I differentiate it with the completely downloaded ones so that I don't process it?

Comment: Well, i don't know how you have implemented the requests. But I would create a list with the urls for download and start threads for each one or join some, depends on your optimization skills. After that, you  can keep checking the size of `Queue` and download if greater than zero. Understood?

Comment: Yeah. I got the gist. I will try. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some sort of message queue could help to cleanly address this problem, and decouple downloading a JSON and processing a JSON.

In this setup:

`[download] -> [MQ] -> [process] -> ??`

Each [] would represent a separate process and -> will represent sending some sort of interprocess data.

Your download script could be modified to save each file to a cloud file storage service, and publish a message with the location of that file, when the download is complete.

There could then be a consumer process which reads from the message queue and processes the file.

This will allow you to process each file as it is download.  Additionally, it lets you scale the download and the process steps separately.

While this pattern is very common, it comes with operation complexity.  You will need to manage 3 separate processes.

If you would like to run this on a single machine you could apply the same pattern locally by having two separate processes:

- [download] - writes to stdout
- [process_json] - reads from stdin and processes the json

then you could link them using os pipes `download.py | process_json.py`

`download.py` would download the file and write the file path.  and process_json would operate on a single filepath.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a ton! But, how does the download.py know when to stdout a particular JSON? I mean, how do I know that the JSON has been completely downloaded so that download.py can stdout it?

My download script [A shell script] just makes all the JSONs download in one command, so I am just confused over how to take each after it has been completely downloaded.

Comment: I am actually trying this, I will have a thread which checks the folder (the one in which JSONs are getting downloaded) every second and check how many JSON files have "last modified" as more than a second from now, then I think I can safely assume that the file has been downloaded completely and can be sent to further processing.

Comment: @Manohar how are you downloading the files in your script? there should be a way to tell from the script if the download has been fully completed or if there was something exceptional that interrupted it?